# valuerror : Null Layer

Tags: file-geodatabase, geopandas, fiona, personal-geodatabase, file-geodatabase-api

I am trying to open a geodatabase file and getting error message `ValuError : Null Layer`.
I am using `geopandas.read_file`.

```
import geopandas as gpd
gdp.read_file("AL_ALFL_conf_final.gdb")
```

I get error `Null Layer: u''`

Comment: Dataset is from https://coast.noaa.gov/slrdata/

Comment: Like I said you need the full path to `AL_ALFL_conf_final.gdb`

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo, .gpd should be .gdb and you probably need the full path to the file geodatabase.

You can also try specifying layer name:

```
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/Downloads/HI_Hawaii_slr_final_dist.gdb', layer='HI_Hawaii_low_0ft')
```

Comment: That was typo here on stackflow..Actual code works for others data sets.   i have tried to list layers using fiona.listlayers(".   ")  and I get banlk [].... data set used is https://coast.noaa.gov/htdata/Inundation/SLR/SLRdata/FL/ALFL_MOB_TLH_slr_raster_data_dist.zip

Comment: Then edit and update your question with the code you are actually using